# Connect and disconnect Classic bluetooth device within application in swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, rssi, external-accessory

I have ios application that connects with Classic Bluetooth device from iPhone settings (using External accessory framework)
Requirement is to connect and disconnect within application for better user experience.
I am to connect within application by following code-

```
EAAccessoryManager.shared().showBluetoothAccessoryPicker(withNameFilter: nil) { (error) in
    print(error?.localizedDescription)
}
```

How disconnection is possible from application only (not to explicitly visiting iphone settings)

Also, is it possible to get rssi value from External accessory framework in swift ?